# Joining or merging a column to a dataframe

Tags: pandas, merge

We have two dataframes exported from Excel. Both have a column called "PN", which was set at the exporting. "First" and "Second" are the variables with those dataframes. "Third" stores a list of coinsidences between the 2 "PN" columns. Pandas Merge method worked without such list, but since the thing now is not working, I added it as well.

```
gnida = []
for h in first['PN']:
        for u in zip(second['PN'], second['P']):
             if h==u[0]:
                 gnida.append(u)
third = pd.DataFrame(gnida)
```

I need values in the second dataframe to be placed on the rows where coinsidence occurs. If I simply merge:

```
fourth = first.merge(second)
```

, columns that have names other than in the first df are added, but the output is 1 row of headings without rows with values.
If I merge

```
fourth = first.merge(third)
```

, I get:
No common columns to perform merge on. Merge options: left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False.
If I state further "left on = "PN", I get:
object of type 'NoneType' has no len().

Thus, how can Merge or Join or whatever the 2 dataframes in order to use one column of the second dataframe as a key, placing values in a new column where coinsidence occurs. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to merge by the index, just use `fourth = first.join(third)`
otherwise, you need to create a `dataframe` from `third`, add the column that you want to merge by, and use:

```
fourth = first.merge(third,on='name_of_the_column')
```

Comment: I stated "PN" as agroment to Merge, since the coinsidences need to be found there, but got as output "keyerror "PN", though both dfs have such column